# Making Qt designer form annotations show up in print composer?

Tags: qgis, qt-designer

Firstly, I am a QGIS novice, and even less so with QT Designer. I was able to figure out how to use QT Designer to make a QGIS Form Annotation. It sync's well with my data, but I have a problem with the form annotation showing up in QGIS Print Composer.

The Text, SVG, and HTML Annotations all show up in the print composer map, but the QT Designer form annotation does not. The first attached image shows the form annotation displays on the main QGIS screen along with the other three default annotation types. The second image show all except the QT Designer form annotation showing in QGIS print composer. I tried to research the issue online but have not come across any resolution.

Can anyone identify the problem and fix?

**QGIS Main Screen**

[image]

**QGIS Print Composer**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The fix for me turned out to be simply upgrading from 2.18 to latest 3.4.4. Form annotations clearly show in Print Composer.

Next step is to figure out why the text and form annotations move and decrease in size once exported to image or pdf formats.